# css bootstrap drop down menu look different in IE

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the [css bootstrap 3.2.0](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

However, when looking at the site in IE there is a think black border around the menu's options and also the drop down menu button looks different.

If you look at the site http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms using IE and then using Chrome you will see the difference.

I am attaching some screenshot to also emphasize the issue.

How can I for this issue by making IE to look like Chrome?

Here is how the menu look in Chrome
[image]
Here is how the options look in Chrome
[image]

This is how the menu look in IE (Ugly square with the arrow)
[image] 
This is how the options look in IE (ugly thick border)
[image]

Comment: As far as I'm aware there's not much to be done regarding the thick black box. Have you considered using something like Select2 to side step the issue? http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: What version of IE is this?

Comment: The IE version is IE Version 11.0.9600.17207

Comment: You cannot fix these problems.. they are browser specific and every browser renders code differently.

Comment: You have to use a select replacement javascript library like Chosen to get around the browser defaults

Comment: It's a good thing Microsoft just announced that IE is going away.....

Answer (score 0):

Every browser renders UI styles differently. It's unlikely that your website visitors will be viewing your website in more than one browser at a time. User controls are common web page elements and your mobile users will thank you for not screwing their mobile experience on your website.

However if there is a design requirement for a custom UI control you'd design a custom select drop-down using HTML, CSS and add behavior layer with a JavaScript library like jQuery or use CSS3 if you don't need support for IE 7 - 9. Also make sure that it works fine on mobile devices, or replace a custom control with a native control at a certain screen resolution. This will depend on a scale of a project and time constraint.

At the very least you can use one of the Bootstrap custom drop-down controls. They will look similar in most browsers.