# Bootstrap 3 <select> styling in IE

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3 and select elements for dropdowns. 
How can I style this ugly black border in IE? (in Chrome all looks fine)

My html looks like:

```
<select class="form-control custom">
   <option>Data 1</option>
   <option>Data 1</option>
   <option>Data 1</option>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance

[image: Select element (dropdown), in dropped down state]

Comment: Selects look fine in Chrome because chrome has its own set of styles for styling selects, not because of Bootstrap. Try opening your site in Firefox. You'll see another different set of styles.

Comment: Yes I know. The same apply for date input. However the question remains: How to style this unacceptable ugly thing in _IE_, shown in the picture

Comment: Don't think these can be styled: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811906/css-bootstrap-drop-down-menu-look-different-in-ie